# How can I pass a JSON array to a javascript function in the C# WebBrowser Control?

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I have following javascript function in my HTML document:

```
function jsFunction(string, jsonArray, string) { ... }
```

An example of `jsonArray` would be following:

```
[
{"name":"foo", "value":"21980"},
{"name":"bar", "value":"100"},
{"name":"foo", "value":"27492328"},
{"name":"bar", "value":"WEB21980001831"}
]
```

I followed the instructions from the post "[Creating an JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898731/creating-an-json-array-in-c-sharp)" in order to create a JSON Array object in C#.

From my Windows Form I should be able to call the JavaScript function like this:

```
 Object[] jsParams = new Object[3];
 jsParams[0] = (Object)"test";
 jsParams[1] = new
 {
     items = new[] {
         new {name = "foo" , value = "21980"}, 
         new {name = "bar" , value = "100"}, 
         new {name = "foo" , value = "27492328"}, 
         new {name = "bar" , value = "WEB21980001831"}
     }
 };
 jsParams[2] = (Object)"test";

 this.webBrowserCtl.Document.InvokeScript("jsFunction", jsParams);
```

However, it doesn't work.
Did I forget something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFunction is 3 parameter.

```
function jsFunction(string, jsonArray, string) { ... }
```

you send 4 argument.

```
 jsParams[0] = (Object)"test";
 jsParams[1] = new
 {
    items = new[] {
        new {name = "foo" , value = "21980"}, 
        new {name = "bar" , value = "100"}, 
        new {name = "foo" , value = "27492328"}, 
        new {name = "bar" , value = "WEB21980001831"}
    }
 };
 jsParams[2] = (Object)"content";
 jsParams[3] = (Object)"test";
```

Delete this line.

```
 //jsParams[3] = (Object)"test";
```

Parse jsonArray and use in jsFunction.

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonArray );
```

Comment: That's correct but that was a mistake by myself where I tested something else. It still doesn't work.

Comment: parse jsonArray and use in jsFunction.
     var data = JSON.parse(jsonArray );

Comment: Which assembly do I have to use for `JSON.parse`? `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.3`?

Comment: in HMTL document.
function jsFunction(string, jsonArray, string) { 
var data = JSON.parse(jsonArray );
.......
}

Comment: Yes but I cant find the JSON namespace

Comment: don't need assembly. you can look an example. https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse

Comment: I can't access html code. Its an external site. I am working from C# Windows Forms

Comment: use Json.Net. 
Parse in c# and send to javascript.
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsParams[1]);

Comment: or
replace html.

Comment: webBrowser1.DocumentText.Replace("function jsFunction(string, jsonArray, string) { ... }","function jsFunction(string, jsonArray, string) { var data = JSON.parse(jsonArray );  ... }");

Comment: There is no method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(param1) with only one Parameter.