# Converting C# array to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am converting my C# array to json in javascript on MVC view as below

```
var selectedPatientGroups = JSON.parse('[@(Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups != null
                                                      ? string.Join(",", Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups)
                                                      : string.Empty)]')
```

if Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups = string[]{ "abc","cd" }  then I will get converted json object as

```
var selectedPatientGroups = [abc,cd]
```

but as json object I am expecting as ["abc","cd"]

I need best solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json Serialization in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278459/json-serialization-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is `SelectedPatientDiscountGroups` array of `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel! Use a JSON library such as Json.NET or the built-in JavaScriptSerializer. It is much more complicated than just quotes.

But if you insist

```
JSON.parse('[@(Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups != null
               ? string.Join(",", Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups.Select(g => "\"" + g + "\"").ToArray()
               : string.Empty)]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the built-in JSON serializer?

```
var selectedPatientGroups = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SelectedPatientDiscountGroups));
```