# Using a byte array to get a dynamic class from a memory map file

Tags: c#, class, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I thought I had this project licked but at the finish line I ran into a big issue...

Here is my class library (MemoryMapTool.cs)

```
using System;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SharedMemoryWorker
{
    public class MemoryMapTool<T> : IDisposable where T: class
    {
        #region Private class variables
        private string m_sLastError = "";
        private MemoryMappedFile mmf = null;
        private MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = null;
        private string m_sMapName = "";
        private T m_oClassObject = null;
        private byte[] memoryBytes = null;
        private int iMapSize = 0;
        private bool bLocked = false;
        private Mutex mxLock = null;
        #endregion

        #region Public properties
        public string MapName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_sMapName;
            }
            set
            {
                m_sMapName = value;
            }
        }

        public T ClassObject
        {
            get
            {
                //Read class object from memory
                accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, memoryBytes, 0, iMapSize);

                //Convert the byte array to a class object
                m_oClassObject = ConvertByteArrayToObject(memoryBytes);

                return m_oClassObject;
            }
            set
            {
                //Write class object to memory
                m_oClassObject = value;

                //Lock the mutex
                mxLock.WaitOne();

                //Convert the class object to a byte array
                memoryBytes = ConvertObjectToByteArray(m_oClassObject);

                //Write the byte array to memory
                accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, memoryBytes, 0, iMapSize);

                //Unlock the mutex
                mxLock.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public MemoryMapTool(string sMapName, T oClassObject)
        {
            try
            {
                //Save the object
                m_oClassObject = oClassObject;

                //Save the map name
                m_sMapName = sMapName.ToLower();

                //Convert the class or struct object to a byte array
                memoryBytes = ConvertObjectToByteArray(m_oClassObject);
                iMapSize = memoryBytes.Length;

                Debug.WriteLine("MapSize:" + iMapSize.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_sLastError = ex.Message;
                throw new NullReferenceException("Error creating new object!");
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Deconstructor
            CloseMemoryMap();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public class methods
        public string GetLastError()
        {
            return m_sLastError;
        }

        public bool OpenMemoryMap()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create new map or use an existing one
                mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(m_sMapName, iMapSize);

                //Lock the mutex
                mxLock = new Mutex(true, m_sMapName + "_ipc", out bLocked);

                //Create the memory map view accessor
                accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, iMapSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

                //Unlock mutex
                mxLock.ReleaseMutex();

            }
            catch
            {
                //Return error
                return false;
            }

            //Return success
            return true;
        }

        public void CloseMemoryMap()
        {
            //Destory the memory map view accessor in needed
            if (accessor != null) accessor.Dispose();

            //Destory the memory map file if needed
            if (mmf != null) mmf.Dispose();

            //Get rid of the mutex lock if needed
            if (mxLock != null) mxLock.Close();
            bLocked = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private class methods
        private byte[] ConvertObjectToByteArray(T sourceObj)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = null;

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, sourceObj);
                byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }

            return byteArray;
        }

        private T ConvertByteArrayToObject(byte[] sourceBytes)
        {
            object newObject = null;

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(sourceBytes))
            {
                newObject = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }

            return (T)newObject;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here is my test application "MyAppA" (Form1.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharedMemoryWorker;

namespace MyAppA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Public classes
        [Serializable()]
        public class MySClass
        {
            public string Test = "Test 1";
            public string Test2 = "Test 2";
            public string Test3 = "Test 3";
            public int Test4 = 4;
        }
        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySClass myClass = new MySClass();
            myClass.Test = "This is my test string";

            using (MemoryMapTool<MySClass> mmt = new MemoryMapTool<MySClass>("testmap", myClass))
            {
                //do stuff
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

So the problem is a simple problem, but I'm not sure about how simple the solution is (if one exists)...  Currently I can use what I have on MyAppA.Form1.button1_Click to take a class object I have on Form1 and create the byte array (using serialization) from the class object (MySClass - AKA myClass).  That works great and I get the...

```
Debug.WriteLine("MapSize:" + iMapSize.ToString());
```

... line to return...

> MapSize:204

Perfect!  And knowing the size is 204 I can also retrieve the memory map by pulling 204 bytes and turning them into the class object again.  Simple!

But wait, there is a problem...  What if I change the myClass.Test string to something like ...

```
myClass.Test = "This is my test string2";
```

Well crud..  Now the size is 205!!!  I guess looking back I kind of expected that anyway.  So what happens when I have another app, say MyAppB using the same code and trying to pull the class object from memory?  The default size (serialized) of...

```
[Serializable()]
public class MySClass
{
    public string Test = "";
    public string Test2 = "";
    public string Test3 = "";
    public int Test4 = 4;
}
```

... is MapSize: 168.  I can adjust my class to calculate the size of the object when i'm writing with no problem, but how do you get it to work when reading?

Comment: just serialize the size at the beginning of your memory-block(?)

Comment: Consider using pipes to communicate between processes instead of memory mappings. That makes sending messages easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing to a binary form, you could serialize to JSON or XML. Of course this will increase the size of your serialized object, but it is much easier to deal with it.
There are several ways to do this. Here's an example I found on this website:

```
var thing = new Thing();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(thing);
```

Your class might need some tweaks before it can be serialized in a standard way like this though.

Source:
[Json Serialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278459/json-serialization-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Could you possibly update your answer with an example?  What's the difference in performance between JSON or XML?  Which one is easier to use?  Also...  Going to XML would create a file right?  I was hoping to not create a file when doing this...

Comment: XML or JSON does not necessarily create a file. XML and JSON are just ways in which objects can be represented in a text-based form. This can then be stored in a string and sent across different systems. This is what happens a lot when generating dynamic web content for example. The request you make is answered by a response that is dynamically generated... even though there is a document, no file exists holding the document that is sent.
You could serialize your data in a similar way. As to performance, I'm sure binary form is faster, but JSON or XML is way easier to handle.

Comment: Would that not yield the same issue?  I have no problem putting it in a byte array or a string, etc...  But getting it from memory is the problem.  For example, If I'm writing a string to memory mystr = "my test 3444" and then I try to retrieve a test string mystr, how many bytes would I pull from memory?  The string could be ANYTHING.  So it might be 20 bytes, or 200 bytes...  Your example is really no different than my method of converting it to a byte array then saving.

Answer (score 0):

As said before by someone else... your problem has to do with the length of the memory mapped data so when you write the file, make sure to write the length of the byte array first.

MMF =>

when you read the file, first read the length descriptor and then init an array of the length read and fill it with data from the mmf.