# Replacing a part of a string from a text file

Tags: c#

I want to replace the second part of the string line of my .txt file. My .txt is:

```
admin|admin
ruiliberal|123456789
```

And I want to replace it like this for example:

```
admin|12345
ruiliberal|123456789
```

My code is:

```
string dirConta = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Bd/contas.txt";

private void buttonGravaPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadLines(dirConta).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < File.ReadAllLines(dirConta).Count(); i++)
    {

        string[] parts = lines[i].Split(new char[] { '|' });
        if (parts[0] == Users.user)
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(lines[i].Length - 5);
            lines[i] = lines[i] + "12345";
        }
        File.WriteAllText(dirConta, lines[i]);
    }
}
```

This doesn´t work, it deletes the last line.

Comment: Why call `ReadLines()`, then subsequently call `ReadAllLines()`?  There is so much wrong with this

Comment: Because it doens´t work if I did not @maccettura

Comment: Loop through lines in a file using `File.ReadLines()` in a For Each loop [see here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readlines).

Comment: @RuiLiberal what you are doing does not make sense though, and you cannot claim it works now because the very essence of your question is that it _does not_ work.  You need to read the documentation more.  You should be iterating the return of `File.ReadLines()`, splitting each line inside the loop, build a new string and add that to an "output" list.  Then use `File.WriteLines()` to write back to the file

Comment: So what you're telling is that you store passwords in plain text, against all reason?

Comment: It´s a work for school.. @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code.

First problem is: **never store passwords in plain text**.  This is a *horrible* idea.  If this is a production system, stop what you are doing and start from the ground up because this is **bad**. If this is just an exercise in learning and is not for any real future use then continue on...

Second, you are calling [`File.ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2), you dont need both.  Just use `File.ReadLines()` as it returns an `IEnumerable` and lets you work on the results as they come in instead of waiting for all to be returned (which is what `File.ReadAllLines()` does).

Next, you should make a method that actually does the modification for you so you can reuse it if needed:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ModifyLines(IEnumerable<string> inputLines)
{
    foreach(var line in inputLines)
    {
        var split = line.Split('|');
        yield return $"{split[0]}|12345";
    }
}
```

This will iterate the input `IEnumerable`, and `yield return` a new string. There really isn't any reason to modify the `split` array, just take the string you need (the username) and use string interpolation to format it with your static password ("12345").

Then when all is said and done you need to use `File.WriteAllLines()` method to write the results to file, *not* `File.WriteAllText()`.  One of the reasons your code does not work is because you *write all text* inside the loop. If you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see what the method actually does you will see why it would not work the way you are using it.

So all together it would be:

```
private void buttonGravaPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = ModifyLines(File.ReadLines(dirConta));
    File.WriteAllLines(dirConta, lines.ToArray());
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PBcTd8)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my spin on it...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Q_53401300
{
    class Program
    {

        static string dirConta = "C:\\temp2\\ListOfPWD.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            buttonGravaPass_Click(null, null);

        }

        private static void buttonGravaPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> newLinesToWrite = new List<string>();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dirConta))
            {
                string currentLine = string.Empty;
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = currentLine.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    //if (parts[0] == Users.user)
                    //{
                    parts[0] = parts[0].Remove(parts[0].Length - 5);
                    parts[1] = parts[1] + "12345";
                    newLinesToWrite.Add($"{parts[0]}|{parts[1]}");
                    //}
                }
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(dirConta, newLinesToWrite);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you are aware, `File.ReadLines()` uses a `StreamReader` under the hood.

Comment: @maccettura - Correct, but I deal with larger files and StreamReader has been more reliable over time.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to use your code here is the tested working version just change the lines in your code related to the ones below:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(dirConta).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            string[] parts = lines[i].Split(new char[] { '|' });
            if (parts[0] == Users.user)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(lines[i].Length - 5);
                lines[i] = lines[i] + "12345";
            }

        }
        File.WriteAllText(dirConta, string.Join("\n",lines));
```

I hope this help as the other answers pointed what miss with the code.

Answer (score 0):

So in my opinion there are a few things wrong with this code.

1.) Your for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
{ [...] }
```

you do not have to call ReadAllLines() again.
Or do:

```
foreach(string line in lines){[...]}
```

2.) Splitting into the parts:
Since you only have one splitting char you can call that like that:

```
string[] parts = lines[i].Split('|');
```

3.) Assigning the new string value:
Why not just do that:

```
lines[i] = $"{parts[0]}|12345";
```

4.) I would not suggest to write to the file in every loop. Just put `File.WriteAllText(dirConta, lines[i]);` outside your for-loop

5.) If you want to store data, I would strongly suggest to look into object-serialization. It makes alot of stuff easier.
See: [Json Serialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278459/json-serialization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your approach. First, you should try to avoid `+` when concatenating strings. Use `$""` or `string.Format` instead. Second, when event-programming, it's best to write another method that the event method calls so that you can avoid blocking the UI thread with unnecessary work (like writing to a file for example). Looking at the documentation for `System.IO`, it's possible to iterate over the lines of text using `File.ReadLines` so I did that instead of reading the file twice to get the number of lines. Also, instead of using `Remove` and `+`, just use `Replace`; it's much easier. Finally, you need to make sure you write *all* the text you have. Right now, you're only writing the first line.

```
string dirConta = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/Bd/contas.txt";

private async Task ModifyFileAsync()
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(dirConta))
    {
        while ((var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
        {
            var parts = line.Split('|');
            if (parts[0] == Users.user)
            {
                var newLine = line.Replace(parts[1], "12345");
                lines.Add(newLine);
            }
            else
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(dirConta))
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}

private async void buttonGravaPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ModifyFileAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```